# Windows 7 allowed bulk rename of folders in search results but wont let me rename them back

Tags: windows-7, search, rename

So I did a search for a parent folder with several subfolders with subfolders within them.  I searched for DRAWINGS and got several hundred results.  I tried renaming the results to DRAWINS -(1) hoping they would rename with unique -(2), -(3), etc... so that I can copy them to a working folder on my hdd.

It didn't uniquely rename them so they all say -(1).  So, I tried to rename them back to DRAWINGS so they would all be named the same again.

These DRAWINGS folders are all in different subfolders so they should be allowed to have the same name, such is the reason they all didn't rename with unique names in my first attempt.

Now Windows wont let me rename them and it is saying they are all being used by another user or software.

Are there any suggestions or comments concerning this situation that might help me understand why Windows 7 would let do something one time but wont let me do the same thing another time?

Right now another piece of software that is looking for drawings with unique part number names in a parent folder named DRAWINGS is unable to find them now because the folders are named DRAWINGS -(1).

Answer (score 0):

First close all your Windows Explorer windows and then open it up again and try to rename one of those troubled folders.  If that doesn't work (normally it will), rebooting your system will allow you to start renaming your folders again.

What you didn't state was if the folders you were renaming were on your local computer or on a server.  If they are on a server, you may need to contact an Administrator for some assistance.

Rationale: Windows has cached the fact that a user (you) is still using the folders, even though you are not in them. It's a fluke of how Windoze works.  I run into this all the time on my systems.